# Why the centre of Newton's rings is dark?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Why the centre of [Newton's rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_rings) is dark? At the point of contact there is absolutely no air film between lens and glass sheet. then how can light reflected from this point produce destructive interference?

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for an answer? eg Wikipedia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newton's rings experiment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91371/)

Comment: Yes I have spent almost 2 hours searching on internet. But all are beating about the bush. The question you referred does not address my query satisfactorily. Tell me what happens exactly at the point of contact?

Comment: Have you read the answers in the "possible duplicate" question? What is unsatisfactory about these answers? Farcher's explanation is particularly simple.

Comment: The central fringe is not necessarily dark, as can be seen in this image https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_rings#/media/File%3A20cm_Air_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

A student asked me this recently during my lab TA duty.

My reasoning was the following points to pmder upon:

1. If there was really no air film, how can there be reflection and subsequent interference? Wouldn't the rays trasmit as the media would be continuous (glass).
2. Actually, the point of contact is just a single point. Notice that the central dark fringe is not a single point, but has a finite area. The area just around the contact point is giving interference fringes, and they have air between them, but the path difference of interfering rays is still very close to zero, hence the dark fringe.
3. Moreover, there is often a miniscule dirt or particle at the point of contact, so the plates are not exactly touching anymore. Depending on the size and refractive index of particle, the central fringe may even be bright. Have you ever observed it?

Comment: 2. All real materials (including glass) deform to some extent, so the contact area will be finite, especially if the lens radius of curvature is large. If the path difference (for reflection) is close to zero then the central fringe should be *bright* not dark. The extent of any ring (including the central one) is not sharply defined; rings fade in and out as the phase difference varies from minimum to maximum.

Comment: But if you talk about deformation, the surfaces are irregular and therefore minute air is between them. I repeat, if surfaces are smooth and perfectly touching then there is no interface and no reflection so no fringe at all!

Comment: Isn't it possible that the point of contact is infinitesimally small and it gives a bright spot but this spot is too small to be seen even with a microscope?

Comment: @rock : The answers in the duplicate together explain that where there is a small air gap there will be destructive interference of reflected light (because of the phase change on internal reflection), and where there is no air gap at all there will be perfect transmission, no reflection. Either way, the centre is dark, even under a microscope.

Comment: @rock, exactly that's what I want to say. Even if there is perfect contact point, there is no reflection there (same medium so transmission) and no interference. And where there are minuscule air pockets, there is dark spot (zero path difference and pi phase change at rare-dense interface).

Comment: @sammy, that's a right point you made about deformation. The irregularities at the deformation are filled with air so the dark spot. The deformation is actually the reason for the large spot.

Comment: I got it. In Newton's rings experiment there is a glass sheet lying at 45 degrees with horizontal. It sends light down to air film by total internal reflection. why does it not bend the reflected light coming from film, towards the source by the same principle?

Comment: It is not total internal reflection, but just normal reflection. There is both reflection and transmission, so ideally it is a 50 50 beam splitter. If source is giving intensity I, I/2 falls on plates and interfere, and I/4 is visible to you.